# Autofiltering Pivot and Non-pivot Columns using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a pivot table from column B to column N. On the left, in column A, there's some data for which I used the content in the pivot table to look up for some values. On the right, in column O to X, there's also some other data which are calculated based on the pivot table's content.

I need to filter column X = 1 and then column V = 0. Below are my codes:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, LastCell As Long

Set ws= ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
LastCell = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row  

ws.Range("$A$4:$X$" & LastCell).AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:="1"
ws.Range("$A$4:$X$" & LastCell).AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:="0"
```

Problem is, I get "Run-time error '1004': AutoFilter method of Range class failed".

But the code that I get from recording the macro is not that far off either, I just added my own variables:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$X$900").AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:="1"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$X$900").AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:="0"
```

I tried to run back the recorded code afterwards, and I get the same error. What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: does column B have a last cell that is greater than 4?

Comment: And I wouldn't normally place a pivottable in a filter range. Is there a reason why you are including it in your filter range?

Comment: @QHarr yes, the last data is in B900. I'm filtering in this way cause the calculation I get in column X and V are the qualifiers that I need for the data in the pivot table.

Comment: Why not include a field in the pivot that you can use?

Comment: You mean like insert calculated field to the pivot? Hmm, considering I use column O to X to calculate, it's a lot harder to insert multiple fields

Comment: Are o to x referencing the pivot to make the calculations?

Comment: Yes, they are. Column A is looking up based on the pivot too

Comment: Have you tried first clearing all previous filters? something like `If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.AutoFilter`?

Comment: Be careful with arranging other data around a pivot table. A pivot table can change the number of columns or rows at any time, based on different data or a change in the field order. This can directly affect adjacent data (more to the right than the left). I've had more success by keeping the pivot table on a separate sheet and all my "other" data for filtering on a different sheet. Though it might mean a small redesign, it may make it much easier in the long run.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I tried, but that didn't help either  =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, I got the answer after trying to explore some other ideas.

Instead of using:

```
ws.Range("A4:X" & LastCell).AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:="1"
ws.Range("A4:X" & LastCell).AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:="0"
```

I used:

```
ws.Range("A4").AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:="1"
ws.Range("A4").AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:="0"
```

I noticed this as I was trying to use autofilter manually on Excel. I highlighted the whole data and was unable to click the filter button. Normally, it doesn't matter whether you only select a cell or the whole sheet, but since I'm using autofilter on pivot table as well, the only way I was able to use it is by selecting any cell other than the pivot table's.